# Whenever I click on button the view won't open and give me this warnings, what am I doing wrong in this code

Tags: xcode, button, swiftui

The code below gives me warning in the button part and if I run the view won't open.

If I try using NavigationLink a arrow comes at end and I don't want to use navigation in any ways.

I tried the button view putting in NavigationLink link but when I click It the whole form has the click event effect, as if ram clicking the whole form.

```
import SwiftUI
//login view
    struct login: View {
        @State private var usern:String=""
        @State var navigated = false
        @State private var pass:String=""
        @State private var secured:Bool=true
        var body: some View {
                NavigationView{
//textfield and password field
                    Form{
                        VStack{
                        HStack{
                    Text("UserName:")
                    TextField("", text:  $usern)
                        }
                            HStack{
                            Text("Password:")
                                if secured{
                                    SecureField("",text:$pass)
                                }
                                else{
                                    TextField("",text: $pass)
                                }
                                Button(action: {self.secured.toggle()}){
//password seen or unseen
                                    if secured{
                                        Image(systemName:"eye.slash")
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        Image(systemName:"eye")
                                    }
                                }.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                            }
                            Button("Login",action: {signup()}).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
 //button view not working
                            Button("Not Yet signed? Create new account",action: {signup()}).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle()) 
//button view not working
                    }
                }
        }
        
    }
}
    
struct login_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        login()
    }
}

//SIGNUP VIEW 
import SwiftUI

struct signup: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct signup_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        signup()
    }
}
```

Comment: What warning says?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You haven't actually said how you want to show your signup screen. Do you want it in a sheet or a new view? Also, the warnings are because you can't just put a `View` into the action portion of a `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the button is to call an action, to toggle something.
To solve your problem you have to:

Add a State variable to login View

```
struct login: View {
    @State private var usern:String=""
    @State var navigated = false
    @State private var pass:String=""
    @State private var secured:Bool=true
    @State var showSignUp:Bool = false -- this one
}
```

Change the button definition FROM

```
Button("Not Yet signed? Create new account",action: {signup()}).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
```

TO

```
Button("Not Yet signed? Create new account",action: {showSignUp.toggle()}).buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showSignUp) {
                        signup()
                    }
```

Please notice that, for this case I've used **.sheet(isPresented)** to call the view.